a nice probability inequality

Given two events $A$ and $B$, prove that $$P(A|A \cup B) \geq
 P(A|B).$$ Note: $P(A|B)=\dfrac{P(AB)}{P(B)}\\
P(A\cup B|C)=P(A|C)+P(B|C)-P(AB|C)\\
P(A|B)P(B)=P(B|A)P(A)\quad (\text{Bayes formula})\\
P(AB)=P(A\cap B)$.

My attempt:
$P(A|A\cup B)=\dfrac{P(A\cup B|A)P(A)}{P(A\cup B)}(\text{Bayes formula})
=\dfrac{(P(A|A)+P(B|A)-P(AB|A))P(A)}{P(A\cup B)}=\dfrac{(1+P(B|A)-P(AB|A))P(A)}{P(A\cup B)}=\dfrac{P(A)}{P(A\cup B)}$.
So, the inequality becomes $$P(A)P(B)\geq P(A\cup B)P(AB)$$
I don't know how to continue. Could someone help me or have another way to prove the inequality? Thanks in advance!

Out of practice for these...  Wouldn't $P(A|A \cup B)$ be $1$ since $A \subset A \cup B$ is known to have occurred?

@EricTowers $A\cup B$ means that one of $A,B$ has occurred, not necessarily both.

@MaxChien : Wow.  What an anti-intuitive reuse of notation...

@EricTowers It seems reasonable to me. if $X,Y$ are sets then $a\in X\cup Y$ says that $a\in X$ or $a\in Y$, but not necessarily both. This is analogous.

I agree with the comment of peterwhy, that this question is a duplciate..  I have added an answer, which tries to express things more simply, to the originally posted question.

@MaxChien : I read $P(A|B \cup C)$ as "probability of $A$ in a universe in which the union of $B$ and $C$ is true".  Reading $B \cup C$ as "$B$ exclusive-or $C$ exclusive-or ($B$ and $C$)" is bizarre.

@EricTowers The use of $\cup$ here seems consistent with other questions, like Probability of a Union.

@EricTowers I'm not sure I agree that this is bizarre. For set based unions $X\cup Y=(X\setminus Y)\sqcup (Y\setminus X)\sqcup (X\cap Y)$ and this is the same.
